# Textures from Substance look sharp at UV seams

Tags: texturing, uv, normals

I exported my textures from Substance Painter and I wanted to make some renders but I get this weird shading at the UV seams. The edges aren't marked as sharp, I've smoothed the vectors, the Normal node is non-color. Where is the issue coming from?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your object or at least a part of it, don't forget to pack the image

Comment: First, rule in/out the cause.  Are seams still visible on disconnecting normal map, for example, or are they visible in all textures?  There are two main concerns when using SP + Blender in conjunction: 1) OGL vs DirectX coordinate systems; to use in Blender, you want an OGL bake (if you have a DX bake, you can invert G channel of normal map instead); 2) SP and Blender do not triangulate meshes in the same way, and this affects normals + UV interpolation; triangulate meshes before sending to SP.

Comment: I checked my maps and inverting the green channel does help, but the problem seems to be in the low poly model. Even in Substance Painter the textures bake from the HP model well, but when I look at the actual texture the UVs act like individual planes if that makes sense. Here's the model [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=YapLk8Rv" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/YapLk8Rv/)